# How can i add multiple row support to FlexSlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I'm using [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) on my Wordpress site. Everything working good. But i want my gallery visible 2 row. I searched it but not found a solution.

This is my flexslider.js: http://pastebin.com/3YgKEFB4

Answer (score 3):

Try out this approach.
I have tried and it worked for me :)

```
function make2Rows(iWidth) {
    var iHeight = parseFloat($('.flexslider .slides > li').height());
    $('.alliance-list .slides > li').css('width', iWidth+'px');
    $('.alliance-list .slides > li:nth-child(even)').css('margin', iHeight+'px 0px 0px -'+iWidth+'px');
}

$(window).load(function() {
    var itemCnt = 5; // this will be the number of columns per row
    var iWidth = parseFloat($('.flexslider').width() / itemCnt);
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshowSpeed: 1000,
        animationSpeed: 300,
        animationLoop: false,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow: false,
        touch: true,
        itemWidth: iWidth,
        minItems: itemCnt,
        maxItems: itemCnt,
        start: make2Rows(iWidth)
    });
});
```

It works for 2 rows. It defines a function to add margins to the even slides so that they become under the odd ones.
The source of this solution is here:

http://paulgonzaga.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/how-to-create-multiple-row-carousel-on.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

flexslider doesn't support multiple rows. You will either have to code it yourself or have someone add the functionality for you

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate sliders and where you initialize them in Javascript use the before and directionNav parameters to make them work together as if they are a single two-row slider. Here's an example:

```
   $('#slider-row-1').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    before: function(slider){
        $('#slider-row-2').flexslider(slider.animatingTo);
    }, // animates second row in sync with first row
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true, // shows navigation arrows
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 4,
    maxItems: 4,
    slideshow: false
  });

  $('#slider-row-2').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false, // hides navigation arrows
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 4,
    maxItems: 4,
    slideshow: false
  });
```

Then update your styles so that it looks like a single slider:

```
#slider-row-1 .flex-direction-nav a {
    top: 100%;
}
```